# List different commits between two branches by using nodegit

Tags: javascript, git, github, nodegit, node-github

In my program, I'm using nodegit. I'm able to list commits using nodegit:

```
var nodegit = require("nodegit");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

var shas = [];
var names= [];
var mess= [];
var sums= [];
var time =[];
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    nodegit.Repository.open(path.resolve(__dirname, "repo_dir/.git"))
        .then(function(repo) {
            return repo.getMasterCommit();
        })
        .then(function(firstCommitOnMaster){
        // History returns an event.
        var history = firstCommitOnMaster.history(nodegit.Revwalk.SORT.TIME,nodegit.Revwalk.SORT.REVERSE);
        var sh = [];
        var t =[];
        var m = [];
        var names = [];
        var s = [];
        var nfiles = [];
        var numfiles = [];

        // History emits "commit" event for each commit in the branch's history

        history.on("commit", function(commit) {


            t.push([commit.date().getDate(),commit.date().getMonth()+1,commit.date().getFullYear()]);
            m.push(commit.message());
            sh.push(commit.sha());
            names.push(commit.committer().name());
            s.push(commit.summary());
            if(commit.sha()==firstCommitOnMaster.sha()){

                resolve([t,m,sh,names,s,numfiles]);
            };
        });


        history.start();

    })

    .done();
}).catch(function(e){console.log(e)});

promise.then(result =>{
    time=result[0];
    mess=result[1];
    shas = result[2];
    names = result[3];
    sums = result[4];
    nf = result[5];
let student = {  
    t: time,
    m: mess, 
    shsh: shas,
    n: names,
    sum: sums, 
    numf: nf,
};

let data = JSON.stringify(student, null, 2);  
fs.writeFileSync('fileJ.json', data, (err) => {  
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Data written to file');
}); 

}).catch(function(e){console.log(e)});
```

But my problem is to do the same thing but in commits listed different commits between two branches by using nodegit.

What I'm found is mostly in GitBash by commend:

```
$ git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline feature...branch
```

My code should Compare master with a brunch like in this tool on site :
[Compare tool on a site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0VVk.png)

Then get all the commits and stored information in JSON like in a code for the master.
Thank you all for any help.